# Huge query times when sort applied

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have a collection in MongoDB at about 1.1 million records. The average object size is 7.4kb so the database is around 8gb. I have an application which parses through the collection, but must be done synchronously ordered by the endedAt date in each record. It is also important that these are not live games (isLive: false), because otherwise the endedAt date won't exist. Once a record has been parsed, in order to ensure it isn't pulled in again, I set a value of isComplete: true to the record.

Now because the data must be returned to me the earliest first according to the endedAt date, I run the sort() function on the set. This seems to be a huge bottleneck for me right now.

My query for getting the next X rows to parse (remember, these need to be synchronous) is as follows:

```
db.matches.find({ isComplete: { $exists: false }, isLive: false }).limit(n)
```

When n is simply 5, the speed of the query is:
**0.22s**

However, when I add the necessary sort to the same query, because I absolutely must only return the next n rows by the earliest endedAt date (if they haven't already been parsed), the query time increases substantially to:
**46.5s**

The strange thing is, I've managed to parse a few hundred thousand games without problem, and the queries have gotten slower and slower until now where they effectively time-out. To most people this would immediately sound like an index problem, however I have indexes on the following fields:

```
idx_startedAt (1)
idx_endedAt (1)
idx_isComplete (1)
idx_isLive (1)
```

I'm not sure what else I should be indexing to increase the speed of this query, but I'm becoming pretty lost as to how best approach this problem. Any help as always much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to index all of the filter criteria using a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/), including the [sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#sort-order).

Filtering only a single field will still require scanning a large number of documents from disk and then sorting the results in memory. Indexing all of the fields, including the sort, will minimize the number of documents read from disk and prevent the need to sort the results in memory.

The ideal index for this query would be the following:

```
  db.matches.createIndex({ "isLive" : 1, "isComplete" : 1, "endedAt" : 1 }, { "background" : true } )
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried a compound index with not much better results. What's interesting is if I search for where isComplete $exists : true, I get results in around 1s - but when I check for $exists : false, again a huge query and often time-out as a result.. Perhaps the type of index should be different on this field...

Comment: It's somewhat difficult to say without a better understanding of the size of the data being processed or the environment. Would you be able to look through the log file and pull out the log message for the query? This will show important information such as the number of index entries being scanned, documents being scanned from disk, and if results are being sorted in memory. The query parameter change could be greatly reducing the number of documents being read, which would explain the shorter query time.